# Boolean expressions for a tagging system in SQL

Tags: sql, boolean, tagging

Having this SQL tables for a tagging system:

```
CREATE TABLE tags (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100)
);
CREATE INDEX tags_name_idx ON tags(name);

CREATE TABLE tagged_items (
    tag_id INT,
    item_id INT
);
CREATE INDEX tagged_items_tag_id_idx ON tagged_items(tag_id);
CREATE INDEX tagged_items_item_id_idx ON tagged_items(item_id);

CREATE TABLE items (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    content VARCHAR(255)
);
```

The user's boolean expression query "**tag1 AND tag2**" in SQL is:

```
SELECT items.* FROM items
    INNER JOIN tagged_items AS i1 ON (items.id = i1.item_id) INNER JOIN tags AS t1 ON (i1.tag_id = t1.id)
    INNER JOIN tagged_items AS i2 ON (items.id = i2.item_id) INNER JOIN tags AS t2 ON (i2.tag_id = t2.id)
WHERE t1.name = 'tag1' AND t2.name = 'tag2';
```

How do you translate other queries with boolean expressions, such as "**tag1 OR tag2 AND tag3**" ...or even more complex queries such as "**tag1 AND (tag2 OR tag3) AND NOT tag4 OR tag5**" to SQL?

Comment: Could you add the table DATA please?

Comment: Maybe he means "SELECT data.* FROM items", otherwise items is undefined.

Comment: Yeah, I had it wrong in the SELECT (fixed the post now)... sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that data -> items, word -> name and tagged_item -> tagged_items.

This is for "**tag1 AND (tag2 OR tag3) AND NOT tag4 OR tag5**". I'm sure you can figure out the rest.

```
SELECT items.* FROM items
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT i1.item_id FROM tagged_items AS i1 INNER JOIN tags AS t1 ON i1.tag_id = t1.id AND t1.name = 'tag1') AS ti1 ON items.id = ti1.item_id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT i2.item_id FROM tagged_items AS i2 INNER JOIN tags AS t2 ON i2.tag_id = t2.id AND t2.name = 'tag2') AS ti2 ON items.id = ti2.item_id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT i3.item_id FROM tagged_items AS i3 INNER JOIN tags AS t3 ON i3.tag_id = t3.id AND t3.name = 'tag3') AS ti3 ON items.id = ti3.item_id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT i4.item_id FROM tagged_items AS i4 INNER JOIN tags AS t4 ON i4.tag_id = t4.id AND t4.name = 'tag4') AS ti4 ON items.id = ti4.item_id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT i5.item_id FROM tagged_items AS i5 INNER JOIN tags AS t5 ON i5.tag_id = t5.id AND t5.name = 'tag5') AS ti5 ON items.id = ti5.item_id
WHERE ti1.item_id IS NOT NULL AND (ti2.item_id IS NOT NULL OR ti3.item_id IS NOT NULL) AND ti4.item_id IS NULL OR ti5.item_id IS NOT NULL;
```

**Edit:**
If you want to avoid subqueries, you could do this:

```
SELECT items.* FROM items 
    LEFT JOIN tagged_items AS i1 ON items.id = i1.item_id LEFT JOIN tags AS t1 ON i1.tag_id = t1.id AND t1.name = 'tag1'
    ...
WHERE t1.item_id IS NOT NULL ...
```

I'm not sure why you'd want to do it though, as the additional left joins will likely result in a slower run.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid using nested SELECTs when possible? as in the "tag1 AND tag2" example I gave.