# MySQL many-to-many setup - How to convert boolean expression to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, boolean-expression

This may seem like a strange question, but here goes...

I have a table structure similar to this:

```
Object
id, name
```

---

```
Tag
id, name
```

---

```
ObjectTag
object_id, tag_id
```

---

What I want to be able to do is to take a boolean expression like

```
((1 OR 2) AND (3)) AND (!4 AND !5)
```

and convert it to a valid MySQL query. The numbers in these boolean expressions represent `tag_id`s. We want to be able to find all of the `object_id`s that satisfy the boolean expression.

In this case, if we had `object1` that had `tag1`, and `tag3`, but did not have any relation to `tag4`, or `tag5`, we would get it back in the return statement.

Similarly, if we had `object2` that had `tag2` and `tag3`, but also had `tag4`, we would not return it, because the `AND (!4 AND !5)` means we don't want an `object_id` returned if it has one of those tags.

I think the logic of the boolean expression is simple enough, but converting it to something in MySQL that doesn't use a whole bunch of EXISTS statements and is somewhat simple does not seem to exist (for me, with my limited experience).

On a side note, the expressions can potentially be much more advanced (and nested). I am also getting this input and parsing it programmatically.

Another question similar to this one is [Boolean expressions for a tagging system in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830015/boolean-expressions-for-a-tagging-system-in-sql). My problem with that question is that it is very specific (where I'm trying to take a programmatic approach) and it seems quite complex to me, but I'm not sure if I can avoid that or not, hence me writing this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a very good fit for using `group by` and `having`.  Here is how your expression would be expressed:

```
select ot.object_id
from objecttag ot
group by ot.object_id
having (sum(ot.tagid in (1, 2)) > 0 and
        sum(ot.tagid = 3) > 0)
       ) and
       sum(ot.tagid in (4, 5)) = 0;
```

Comment: I cannot believe how simple you made this query... this is great! Thank you for your input! I had really over-complicated this thing. So, since I don't know a ton about MySQL, what does 'having' do exactly? I've never seen that before...

Comment: @NicholausChipping . . . `having` works like a `where` clause only it is executed *after* the `group by` so it can work with aggregation functions.